# PHP unittest mock return error "Mock queue is empty"

Tags: php, phpstorm, юнит-тесты, phpunit

При использовании mock в `unit` тестах возникла вот такая ошибка `Mock queue is empty`. Искал по разному - но так и не нашел решение.

Ошибка возникает когда я в одной функции два раза вызываю метод `sendRequest`.

В первом случаи (запрос `POST`) он отдает данные с mock файла. Второй (запрос `PUT`) же запрос выдает  `Mock queue is empty`.

**В условие:**

```
if ($auth == false) if (!is_null($this->mockSubscriber)) $client->getEmitter()->attach($this->mockSubscriber->getMock($stream . '_' . $method));`
```

заходят оба запроса.

Через `debug` видно что `mock` при инициализации прочитал оба файла с ответами.

Запросы отправляю через `guzzlehttp/guzzle 5.3.0`

```
class ClientTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{
    protected $clientWallet;

    protected function setUp(){
    $url = "***";
    $userName = "***";
    $password = "***";
    $grantType = "***";
    $appKey = '***';

    $cfgData = new PayClient\Configuration(
        [
            'url' => $url,
            'username' => $userName,
            'password' => $password,
            'grantType' => $grantType,
            'appKey' => $appKey
        ]
    );

    /*
    *   WalletTopUp logger and mocks
    */

    // Initialize logger.
    $logger = new \Monolog\Logger("WalletTopUp");
    $logger->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler("WalletTopUp_test.log"));

    // Initialize mock subscriber Wallet.
    $mockWallet = null;
    $useMockResponseWallet = true;
    if ($useMockResponseWallet) {
        $mockWallet = new MockSubscriber(
            __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' .
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'mocks');
    }
    // Create Wallet Top Up Client
    $this->clientWallet = new \maviance\WalletTopUpClient\WalletTopUpClient($cfgData, $mockWallet);
    $this->clientWallet->addLogger($logger);
    $this->clientWallet->init();
}


    /*
     *  Test Wallet Top Up client
     *
     */
    function testWalletPurchase()
    {        
        $purchaseData = new PurchaseRequestData();
        $purchaseData->setCustomerPhonenumber('0712999267');
        $purchaseData->setAmount(50);
        $purchaseResponse = $this->clientWallet->purchase('wallet', 56438, '', $purchaseData);
    }
}
```

**Класс `WalletTopUpClient`:**

```
class WalletTopUpClient{
    function __construct(Configuration $config, MockSubscriber $mock = null)
    {
        $this->cfgData = $config;
        $this->mockSubscriber = $mock;
        $this->getAuthToken();
    }
    public function purchase($service, $destinationId, $srcRefId, PurchaseRequestData $inputData)
    {
        $body = [
            'Stream' => $service,
            'Amount' => $inputData->getAmount(),
            'PhoneNumber' => $inputData->getCustomerPhonenumber(),
            'PaymentTypeID' => $this::PAYMENT_TYPE_ID
        ];
        $response = $this->sendRequest($service, 'POST', $this->cfgData->getUrl() . '/api/payments/POST', $body);
        $data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);

        $body = [
            'Stream' => $service,
            'TransactionID' => $data['TransactionID'],
            'PhoneNumber' => $inputData->getCustomerPhonenumber()
        ];


        $response = $this->sendRequest($service, 'PUT', $this->cfgData->getUrl() . '/api/payments/PUT', $body);
        $data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        return new PurchaseResponse(
            new PurchaseStatus(PurchaseStatus::SUCCESS),
            \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', $data['TransactionDate']),
            $srcRefId,
            $data['ReceiptNumber'],
            $data['TransactionStatus']);
    }


    function sendRequest($stream, $method, $url, $body = null, $auth = false)
    {
        // Determine body.
        $body = is_array($body) && !$auth ? utils\Utils::toString($body) : $body;
        // Get http client
        $client = $this->getClient();
        if ($auth == false)
            if (!is_null($this->mockSubscriber))
                $client->getEmitter()->attach($this->mockSubscriber->getMock($stream . '_' . $method));
        // Create request.

        $request = $client->createRequest($method, $url, ['body' => $body]);

        if (!$auth) {
            $request->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            $request->setHeader('Authorization', '**** ' . $this->getAuthToken()->access_token);
            $request->setHeader('app_key', $this->cfgData->getAppKey());
        }
        $response = null;
        try {
            $response = $client->send($request);
        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            $this->logger->error("Error sending request: " . $e->getMessage());
            throw new FatalErrorException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error("Error sending request: " . $e->getMessage());
            throw new FatalErrorException($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $response;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все, проблема решена! 
Нужно было после запроса выполнит detach(), что бы обнулился listener моков.
Привожу полный код функции

```
function sendRequest($stream, $method, $url, $body = null, $auth = false)
    {
        // Determine body.
        $body = is_array($body) && !$auth ? utils\Utils::toString($body) : $body;
        // Get http client
        $client = $this->getClient();
        $mock = null;
        if ($auth == false)
            if (!is_null($this->mockSubscriber))
                $client->getEmitter()->attach(($mock = $this->mockSubscriber->getMock($stream . '_' . $method)));

        // Create request.

        $request = $client->createRequest($method, $url, ['body' => $body]);

        if (!$auth) {
            $request->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            $request->setHeader('Authorization', 'bearer ' . $this->getAuthToken()->access_token);
            $request->setHeader('app_key', $this->cfgData->getAppKey());
        }
        $response = null;
        try {
            $response = $client->send($request);
        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            $this->logger->error("Error sending request: " . $e->getMessage());
            throw new FatalErrorException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error("Error sending request: " . $e->getMessage());
            throw new FatalErrorException($e->getMessage());
        }

        // Detach mock subscriber.
        if (isset($mock))
            $client->getEmitter()->detach($mock);

        return $response;
    }
```